# Tailwind-DaisyUI accordion and switch are not working

Tags: tailwind-css, astrojs, daisyui

I have set up Astro project that has [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/) and [Daisy UI](https://daisyui.com/) installed, but I am unable to get Daisy controls to work. I copy/pasted the code from the [accordion page](https://daisyui.com/components/accordion/), but when the page is rendered, the controls do not work. It's like the controls are static text. Range and rating seem to work, but then Switch acts just like a checkbox.

[image: example]

Here is my tailwind.config.cjs

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    darkMode: 'class',
    content: ['./src/**/*.{astro,html,svelte,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    daisyui: {
        themes: ['light', 'dark']
    },
    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontSize: {
                '45xl': '2.7rem',
                '10xl': '10rem',
                '11xl': '12rem',
                '12xl': '14rem',
                '13xl': '16rem',
                '14xl': '18rem'
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/typography'), require('@tailwindcss/forms'), require('daisyui')]
}
```

It looks like DaisyUI loads and the styling works. There are no errors in the DevTools console. What else can I check?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have `@tailwindcss/forms` in your dependencies, which is incompatible with the DaisyUI's accordions.

If you really need the `@tailwindcss/forms` dependency one way is to use [classes to style](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms#using-classes-to-style) instead to let it do atomically all over the elements

Something like this in your `tailwind.config.js`

```
require('@tailwindcss/forms')({ strategy: 'class' })
```

and then go thru all your form elements to manually apply the relative class as per the docs.

But before going thru this refactoring, just try and see if this is your case: remove `require('@tailwindcss/forms')` from your `tailwind.config.js` and see if accordions work.

Comment: Thank you! I removed `@tailwindcss/forms` and the accordion worked. I would never have discovered this.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: In my case, it was conflicting with flowbite and its plugin in tailwind.config.ts file. I removed flowbite related lines and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the `@tailwindcss/forms` plugin enabled, a quick solution to fix this is to add the `w-auto` and `h-auto` classes to the checkbox used  by the collapse/accordion. A working example is:

```
<div class="collapse bg-base-200">
  <input type="checkbox w-auto h-auto" /> 
  <div class="collapse-title text-xl font-medium">
    Click me to show/hide content
  </div>
  <div class="collapse-content"> 
    <p>hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Source](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms/issues/134#issuecomment-1422722725)

Comment: awesome, thank you

Comment: needs to be <input type="radio" name="my-accordion-1" class="w-auto h-auto"/>

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, the example I used was for the collapse component, which is what powers the accordion and other ones.

Answer (score 0):

I use `JSX` and i do not use `require('@tailwindcss/forms')`. Changing this line

```
<input type="radio" name="my-accordion-4" checked="checked" />
```

to

```
<input type="radio" name="my-accordion-4" defaultChecked />
```

did the trick for me.

**Key points:**

- Applies only to radio buttons and checkboxes.
- Typically used for initial states based on user preferences, saved data, or logical starting points.
- Should be used with uncontrolled components (not managed by React state).
- For controlled components (managed by React state), use the checked attribute instead.